# Combination of Spline with Column Highstock Chart

Tags: highcharts

I would like to seek solution for the combination of Spline with Column Highstock Chart. Below is the code that I had written:

var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        zoomType: 'xy'
                    },

```
                xAxis: {
                    minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    ordinal: false
                },

                yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total Count'

                    },
                    height: 150,
                    lineWidth: 2

                }, { // Secondary yAxis
                    title: {
                        text: 'Member Count'

                    },
                    height: 150,
                    opposite: true,
                    lineWidth: 2

                }],

                series: [{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Bet Count',
                    data: bc,
                    dataGrouping: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'spline',
                    name: 'Bet Member Count',
                    data: bmc,
                    yAxis: 1
                }]
            });
```

[image]

Comment: and what's happened? maybe you can post an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: @IgorDymov, hi, please refer to my latest edited post.

Comment: The spline line suppose within the column chart

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong, because spline line and column are prepared correct, based on y values, so maybe you use two yAxis / one for column, one for spline?

Comment: @SebastianBochan hi, I'm think you are right. Then how to make it refer to the same y axis at right side? thank for the reply

Comment: You can use linkedTo parameter as achive the same range in second yAxis or set min/max values in second axis. All optios are aviable here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis